# Can you use Redis alongside Resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, resque

I'm using Redis To Go on Heroku, and I'd like to use it to store some data alongside Resque jobs, much like I can store DelayedJobs in the same Postgres database as the rest of my model data.

Is this possible? Care to explain briefly how Resque stores jobs in Redis? I'm new to Redis, and though I understand on a higher level how it works, I'm unfamiliar with the implementation details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.  According to the Resque documentation:

> Resque has a redis setter which can be given a string or a Redis object. This means if you're already using Redis in your app, Resque can re-use the existing connection.

Also, the documentation for `Resque.redis=` states that a namespace is accepted, to prevent clashes with your other apps running on the same instance:

> A 'hostname:port/namespace' String (to set the Redis namespace)

Check out the "Configuration" section of the Resque readme for more information: https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: Okay so I just need to give the keys unique namespaces and Redis won't get confused by other records, yes?

Comment: Personally I think this is a cleaner solution than my own answer, when you have a namespace it enforces separation of concerns and generally keeps the code in better condition.

Answer (score 1):

[Redis](http://redis.io/) is an advanced key value store which is used by Resque to store data about jobs. Exact details depend on your application however the two should be fine working together. As long as your code stays away from using the lists Resque uses then you will be golden.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering how to do — I assume Resque uses Redis lists, but I don't really know how to avoid touching them or how any of this is accessed. Help?

Comment: Oh! Well that depends on the application, Take the example in the Resque readme the queue is set using `@queue = :file_serve`. In Redis this data is stored using the same name as a list.

Answer (score 1):

yes, completely agree with other answers, the Redis can be used for other purposes, not only for background processing. By the way, Rescue provides easy interface to setup/config/use/browse Redis.

**Setup/Run**

```
$ git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/defunkt/resque.git
$ cd resque
$ rake redis:install dtach:install

$ vim config/resque.yml
  "development: localhost:6379"

$ vim config/initializers/rescue.rb
  "rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
   rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'

   resque_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root + '/config/resque.yml')
   Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]"

$ rake redis:start
```

**Use**

```
# model
 def user_activity
   a = Resque.redis.lrange "log_" + self.id.to_s, 0, -1
   a.map{|i| JSON.parse(i)}
 end
```

**Browse**

```
 $ resque-web
```

It allows you to browse Redis content, not only background processing